# Auto open expandable table when add a new row (Antd table, ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, antd

My expectation: When I click button Add a row, a new row when add to table and expandation of new row will auto open

This is codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-cells-antd-5-1-7-forked-1gwj00

I wanna expandation of new row will auto open when add a row like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkmWr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[Solution for auto expand row when adding](https://codesandbox.io/s/editable-cells-antd-5-1-7-forked-26ptuq?file=/demo.js)